# Possible (simple) typo in Kallenberg, Chapter 10, Lemma 10.2

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Kallenberg writes, in Foundations of Modern Probability, Chapter 10, Lemma 10.2 (pg 179.) that...

$$ \eta \sim Poisson(c) \implies \mathbb{E}e^{a\eta} = e^{-c}\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(ca)^n}{n!} = e^{-c(1-a)} $$

However, isn't the above $\mathbb{E}a^{\eta}$? In particular, $\mathbb{E}e^{a\eta}=\sum_{n \geq 0} e^{an}\frac{e^{-c}c^n}{n!}$, which is not the same as above? I ask because, if it is a typo, then I'm not sure how to prove the lemma, which says that for $\xi$ a Poisson process with intensity $\mu$, $$\mathbb{E}e^{-\xi f}=e^{-\mu(1-e^{-f})}$$  whenever $f$ is measurable, and takes on $\mathbb{R}_+$-values.

Comment: You mean $E[a^\eta]$?

Comment: Yep, correction made @Snoop

Comment: Then it seems to me that you're correct

Comment: Right. I just edited the question to add why the typo matters (for a bigger result that I'm not sure how to prove without assuming this result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a confusion between Laplace and z transform. One is equal to the other, after replacing $z$ by $e^{-s}$.

Let $N$ be a discrete random variable, and let $X$ be a continuous random variable.

Then,

$$N(z) = E[z^N] $$

and

$$X(s) = E[e^{-sX}] $$

are the z transform and Laplace transform, respectively.

Clearly, $$N(e^{-s})=E[e^{-sN}]$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function

The probability generating function is an example of a generating function of a sequence: see also formal power series. It is equivalent to, and sometimes called, the z-transform of the probability mass function.

The generating function of the Poisson random variable is the one you show in your post, and is also given, for instance, at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Correct would be:

$$ \eta \sim Poisson(c) \implies \mathbb{E}a^{\eta} = e^{-c}\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(ca)^n}{n!} = e^{-c(1-a)} $$
and for $\xi$ a Poisson process with intensity $\mu$, $$\mathbb{E}e^{-\xi f}=e^{-\mu(1-e^{-f})}$$  whenever $f$ is measurable, and takes on $\mathbb{R}_+$-values.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I haven't used these transforms in probability in the past.